# How to access refs from app instance in Vue3

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, custom-component

In Vue2 it was possible to access refs from the vue instance like so:

```
vm.$refs.someRef
```

How can I achieve this in Vue3? Access the refs from outside the app instance i.e from js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using options API, it's the same. If you want to use composition API, you pass a `ref` to the template. It gets a little confusing because there are two different refs one is the attribute in the template (`ref="myref"`) and the other is the function `const myref = ref(null)`

When used in the template, the ref value gets updated and can be then accessed via `myref.value`

from https://gitlab.com/mt55/maintegrity-fim-web-interface-server/-/jobs/3293032688/artifacts/download

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

// declare a ref to hold the element reference
// the name must match template ref value
const input = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  input.value.focus()
})
</script>

<template>
  <input ref="input" />
</template>
```

If the ref is needed from outside of the app, it can be accessed through the instance with:

```js
const app=createApp(App)
app._instance?.refs
```

however that only works if the ref is in the App component. For every other component, while the ref is available somewhere in the app object, traversing through the structure is much more complicated.

Comment: That is fine, although my issue is how would I get access of that ref from outside the component (or outside vue). Example, if the above component was used in a Vue app created by createApp(). From that instance of the app, can I access the refs used by components in the app?

Comment: as long as it is in the main(first) vue sfc it loads, you can access with `app._instance?.refs` for the nested objects it's a lot harder, since you need to traverse the structure